# Socket programming vs WCF for thousand of devices

Tags: c#, performance, wcf, sockets

I have a thousand of devices(approx 50000) , to which I have to connect(from ethernet) first and get the data and send some data.So What will be the best idea to implement this.We don't want to continue the connection means after communication cycle complete, the connection should be closed and after 10 second start the process again for every device.

Comment: Do you expect to poll 50,000 devices every 10 seconds from a single client?  That is 0.2msec.  The windows services I don't think will be able to keep up at that rate.  There is a latency in the windows service handling based on the timer tick that will not give an even flow to the connections and will eventually back up and cause a memory leak.

Comment: Client will be single.We are using threadpool .So every thread will handle a device.

Comment: A thread is a process so you will have 50,000 processes running?